# cross referencing papers in a table

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, captions

I have trouble referencing papers in a table. I want to reference papers in a table, where the caption's font is defined using the "caption" package. However, I get ?? in the references in the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers,sort]{natbib}
\usepackage[backref,pageanchor=true,plainpages=false, pdfpagelabels, bookmarks,bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize, labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ c | l } 
    \citep{citation1} & cell\\
\end{tabular}

\caption[short caption]{long caption}
\label{tab:label}
\end{table}

citation in text \citep{citation1}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{cite}

\end{document}
```

It also gives me warnings that say "Package caption Warning: `\label` without proper `\caption` on input line 13" and "LaTex Warning" Reference '??' on page 1 undefined on input line 12. The generated text looks like
[image]

If I comment out the `\usepackage[font=footnotesize, labelfont=bf]{caption}` command the result looks like
[image]
, where the reference generate a pointer only to the text not to the table.

Ultimately, I want to use the "caption" package to define the caption fonts.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `caption` package should be loaded before `hyperref`.

Comment: Thanks @egreg, but I don't find any difference by loading the caption package before hyperref.

Comment: I think that the backreferencing gets confused when a citation is in a float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266562/cross-referencing-papers-in-a-table#comment638872_266562) is correct that the back-referencing gets confused but it does not seem to be a result of back-referencing a citation in a float *per se*.

The problem occurs only if the relevant counter needed for the reference has not yet been incremented by the `\caption...` command. Placing this *before* the table resolves the referencing issue:

[image: working back-reference to citation in float]

Note that the 'document' tag is the back-reference for the citation in the text; the '[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHY1N.png)' is the back-reference for the citation in the table, as can be seen if the citation in the text is removed:

[image: working back-reference to citation in float without distractors]

I don't know much about back-referencing, but I assume the complete lack of document structure is part of the problem since adding a `\section{section}` command also makes it disappear:

[image: example with working back-reference and sectioning command]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers, sort]{natbib}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[backref, pageanchor=true, plainpages=false, pdfpagelabels, bookmarks, bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
%\section{Section}\label{sec:sec}% uncomment this to eliminate the back-reference tagged 'document'
\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\caption[short caption]{long caption}
\label{tab:label}
\begin{tabular}{ c | l }
  \citep{article-full} & cell\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
citation in text \citep{article-full}.% or comment this line instead
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

Note that I've moved the `\label` as well, but this isn't actually important: what matters is the move of the `\caption` command.

[Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266562/cross-referencing-papers-in-a-table#comment638957_266596) suggests that if your document doesn't have the structure of sectional divisions at all, then `pagebackref` may be a better option than `backref`:

```
\usepackage[pagebackref, pageanchor=true, plainpages=false, pdfpagelabels, bookmarks, bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}
```

In that case, a document with the table on page 2 and a citation in the text on page 3 produces these back-references:

[image: back-referencing pages]

This is clearly preferable as far as in-text citations are concerned. However, in this case the reference to the citation in the table is linked to the relevant page rather than to the table specifically. Moreover, this option produces two back-references rather than just one, as would be the case with the same content within a sectional division. This might be an advantage or a disadvantage, of course, depending on your requirements.

Comment: Well, “document” doesn't seem to be a sensible back reference.

Comment: @egreg I don't know anything about back references. Isn't the number rather than the question marks the relevant bit?

Comment: @egreg The 'document' thing is not the link to the citation in the table, but the link to the citation in the text. If you add a `\section{}` command, it disappears. Isn't the 'document' just because the back-referencing is thrown by the fact that the document has no structure whatsoever? At any rate, it seems to be a different issue... ?

Comment: @cfr The `(document)` is just a dummy for the missing section reference. `backref` uses section numbers. If the real document does not have a structure, then `pagebackref` might be the better choice.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I was assuming that the original document probably does have a structure since this is common practice. I guess this can't be known unless the OP says one way or another, though. But the back-reference for the citation in the table works even if the document has no sectional structure, doesn't it? At least, it works when I do some admittedly minimal testing.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Anyway, I hope you won't mind that I've used your comment.

Comment: My original document does have a structure. However, the backref shows ?? when I use the {caption} package and do not show up if I don't have the package. I want it to backref the table that refers the paper.

Comment: @Seungmoon It works for me if the `\caption` is placed before the `tabular` environment containing the citation rather than after it. If it doesn't work for you, perhaps you need to update your TeX installation? I'm using TeX Live 2015. And the link jumps to the correct table for me, too. You do, as usual, have to compile at least twice after running `bibtex` to get this to work.

Comment: Thank you @cfr. Placing the caption above the table also works in my Tex environment. Still, I'm looking for a solution that allows me to keep the caption below the table. I will post a solution if I find one.

Comment: @Seungmoon The `caption` package suggests using something like `floatrow` to alter captions' placement. If you used that, you'd still need to have `\caption` first in the source, but you could have the caption printed beneath the table in the output.

Comment: @cfr using the {floatrow} package and placing the caption above the table solves my problem. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @Seungmoon Great! I thought maybe `caption` could do this but the documentation said not, and I figured it should know ;).